# fast way of converting tar.gz with single file into .gz

Tags: gzip, tar, type-conversion

I have bunch of huge .tar.gz archives that contain one file each. Is there easy and light way of converting them to .gz? Something that will strip TAR header from gzipped file without uncompressing it all?
Something better than `tar xpfvz file.tar.gz -O | gzip > file.gz` please:)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in principle, but I don't know of existing code that can do that.  You will need to roll your own.

You would need to strip the tar header from the compressed data.  You can use zlib to decompress the first deflate block, which should contain all of that header.  (If not, repeat for subsequent blocks.)  You can then remove the header and recompress what remains.  Then append the remainder of the deflate blocks.  The latter would require shifting the rest of the stream by zero to seven bits, since deflate blocks can start and end at any bit location in a byte.  You would need to decompress the remainder as well in order to compute a new CRC to put in the trailer of the gzip stream.